# dynamic create checkbox as array size in swift

Tags: button, checkbox, swift3

I Want to create a view with dynamic create checkbox i know how to create c checkbox dynamic but how to manage size of view?

**Here is my Code:**

```
var spacer: CGFloat = 23

    for comments in fixer as NSArray {
        var counter = ""
        print(comments)
        counter = comments as! String

        let button = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 8, y: 0+spacer , width: 20, height: 20))
        button.setTitle("hi", for: .normal)
        self.assignfixerView.addSubview(button)

        let label = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: 40, y: 0+spacer , width: 80, height: 22))
        label.text = counter
        self.assignfixerView.addSubview(label)
        spacer = spacer + 23
    }
```

**Here is my view :**

[image]

in this user are not fix and i want status(label) and textfield position change and if i create this button than how's the selection process?

**Please give me better /suggestion if any better controller than it will be ok**

**OR any dropdown with multiple selection and after selection all will be display in textfield**

**Thank You in Advanced!**

Comment: Use `tableview` for that

Comment: yes right now i am trying this @NiravD